# Is there any kind of limit with node for I/O?

Tags: node.js, io, v8, nonblocking

I am writing a code that is downloading one file from some place and I am streaming to the client real time. The file is never full in my sever. Only chunks. Here is the code:

```
downloader.getLink(link, cookies[acc], function(err, location) {
    if (!err) {
        downloader.downloadLink(location, cookies[acc], function(err, response) {
            if (!err) {
                res.writeHead(200, response.headers);
                response.pipe(res);
            } else
                res.end(JSON.stringfy(err));
        });
    } else {
        res.end(JSON.stringfy(err));
    }
});
```

As I can see there is nothing blocking this code since response is comming from a simple http.response...
The problem is, this way I can only stream 6 files at the same time. But the server is not using all the resources(cpu 10%, memory 10%) and it is a single core. After +/- 5 files I only get the loading page and the stream doesn't starts, only after some of them has completed.

This is not a limitation on the 1st server where I am downloading the files because using my browser for example I can download as many as I want. Am I doing something wrog or this is some limitation in node that I can change? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is using the node.js core `http` module's `http.Agent`, it has an initial limit of [5 simultaneous outgoing connections to the same remote server](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_agent_maxsockets). Try reading substack's [rant in the hyperquest README](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest) for the details. But in short, try using a different module for your connections (I recommend superagent or hyperquest), or adjust the http Agent's `maxSockets` setting for the node core http module.

Comment: Hello, I changed and still the same. What I've done: var agent = require('http').globalAgent; agent.maxSockets = 500; and then passed to the http.request options agent: agent. Have I done something wrong? thanks I didn't know that and I will try also the superagent and hyperquest.

Comment: Wow, thanks to introducing me to the hyperquest. Looks like is the way to go.. :)

Comment: Well, I've re-implemented my code with hyperquest and the same problem continues. I can't pass over 6 streaming at the same time... after 6 all incomming request is hanging :/

Comment: Are you sure it's not the remote server limiting you? Experiment with other web sites or curl.

Comment: Turns out that was the remote server limiting me. I learned a lot searching for this. Thank you very much Peter!